# Can i use twitter api for select poll votes ? is there any methods in tweepy?

Tags: python-3.x, api, twitter, automation, tweepy

I want to use twitter api for poll votes using tweepy is there any methods to implement this?

I tried doing `api.update_status("poll_1"[1112227775552223333])` but its not working.

Comment: There is no API for interacting with Twitter polls.

Answer (score 0):

No. The poll API is private and is not available to anyone apart from Twitter's own apps.

There are no plans to open this to the public - https://twittercommunity.com/t/poll-support/78235

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is incorrect. There is a way, it's just the JSON data you get back is quite unwieldy (I have plans to build a `tweepy` addon to make this easier). The way to get it with Python 3.x is through `requests`. Don't worry though, it's only a line or so of code. As you can see in this [link](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/data-dictionary/object-model/poll), we can indeed get back twitter poll data. Here's a code snippet:

```
import requests, json, OAuth1

# provided by a Twitter dev account
auth = OAuth1(my_key, my_secret_key, my_access_token, my_secret_access_token) 

tweet_ids_string = "12345678,123456790,09886654333"

# for more expansions see the link above
data_url = f'https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets?ids={tweet_ids_string}&expansions=attachments.poll_ids&poll.fields=duration_minutes,end_datetime,options,voting_status' 

                           
response = requests.get(get_data_url, auth=auth)
response_json = response.json() # then you can get all sorts of data from here
```

Beware though, the Twitter polls API isn't lightning fast, so there might be several seconds of a delay between a poll getting voted on and the request JSON changing.